# Mysql issue when creating a new user

Tags: mysql, database, mariadb

```
( SELECT DISTINCT User
                , Host 
             FROM mysql.user 
) UNION 
( SELECT DISTINCT User
                , Host
             FROM mysql.db 
) UNION 
( SELECT DISTINCT User 
                , Host 
             FROM mysql.tables_priv 
) UNION 
( SELECT DISTINCT User
                , Host 
             FROM mysql.columns_priv 
) UNION 
( SELECT DISTINCT User
                , Host 
             FROM mysql.procs_priv 
) ORDER 
     BY User ASC
      , Host ASC
```

```
Mysql said:
`#1030 - Got error 176 "Read page with wrong checksum" from storage engine Aria`
```

[image: Error here]

Comment: This is a MariaDB question not MySQL, From what i know it would not be possible to install (compile)/run Aria engine on MySQL .. ..

Comment: ... never mind made mine comment to fast it seams.. [Aria FAQ](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/aria-faq/) ->. *"Aria is a storage engine for MySQL® and MariaDB. It was originally developed with the goal of becoming the default transactional and non-transactional storage engine for MariaDB and MySQL. "*

Comment: ... you are not the only one with this problem it seams -> https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-18341  .. The text *"Not reproducible right away."*  underneat it does not sound good suggests that they have no idea (jet) what causes that error...

Comment: @RaymondNijland - OTOH, has anyone plugged Aria into MySQL?

Comment: Try mysqlcheck or `CHECK TABLE`.

Comment: *"has anyone plugged Aria into MySQL?"*  i assume OTOH means On The Other Hand ? @RickJames ? Anyhow No idea  i also was surprised to reading on the manual pages that Aria was designed to also run on MySQL

Comment: @RaymondNijland - The Engine plugin mechanism was added to MySQL almost 2 decades ago (version 4.0?)  I would expect that the simplest way to add Aria in the first place (when MariaDB decided to invent it), would be as a plugin.

Comment: i know @RickJames MariaDB is designed as drop in replacement for MySQL but still some things might be implemented/re-implemented different in the code source. ..   i once tryed in the past to get [MariaDB ColumnStore](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/mariadb-columnstore/) working in MySQL for some reason (which i can not remember anymore) i could never got it to work with the out of the box code..

Comment: Does this answer your question? [#1030 - Got error 176 "Read page with wrong checksum" from storage engine Aria](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60864367/1030-got-error-176-read-page-with-wrong-checksum-from-storage-engine-aria)

Answer (score 5):

Don't really know if the cause of the issue is same, but I fixed this issue with `mysqlcheck`. Run

```
mysqlcheck -c  -u root -p --all-databases
```

in terminal (after you run this, you will be prompted for root password if you have set it).

Running this and browsing through the output, I found the issue was with `tables_priv` table in `mysql` database. So I repaired it using the `-r` flag of `mysqlcheck`.

```
mysqlcheck -r mysql tables_priv -u root -p
```

(again, it will prompt for password, enter it). And that fixed it. Don't really know the cause of the issue, but hope this can help anyone else who faces same issue.

You can also run

```
mysqlcheck -u root -p --auto-repair -c -o --all-databases
```

to automatically fix all corrupted tables without needing to find which one is corrupted (don't know if this will affect any of your other tables negatively, so try the first option and try this if you fail).

You can get more info about `mysqlcheck` from [here](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/12/mysqlcheck/)

Comment: I'm receiving, Error: mysqlcheck doesn't support multiple contradicting commands.

Comment: @XPD which command were you executing when you got that Error? Btw, you should check out [this post](https://serverfault.com/q/291117/533170) which tells more about the error you got

Answer (score 5):

I also ran into the

> "Error: mysqlcheck doesn't support multiple contradicting commands"

issue using the following command

```sql
mysqlcheck -u root -p --auto-repair -c -o --all-databases
```

What I did, and its because I am lazy lol, was run everything separately and used the `-r` for repair instead of `--auto-repair`

```sql
mysqlcheck -u root -p -r --all-databases
mysqlcheck -u root -p -c --all-databases
mysqlcheck -u root -p -o --all-databases
```

Comment: I can't spot this error message in the OP. How's your answer related?

Comment: it is related to the post just above this one user XPD commented and said he had the issue. Arun A S asked what command was being used when he got the error.

It is why I said "Sorry I could not add a comment to the above post but I am unable to make comments yet."

Comment: you saved me mate

Answer (score 0):

I'm using ASUS TUF Gaming A15 - 8gb memory / Windows 11 Home.

I found a solution for the problem of developers who install XAMPP but having problems out of the box with Aria Engine and PhpMyAdmin pma privilege access.

Found out today that if the memory is too low, like 1gb less is free the errors show up after installation. The pma user is not showing up on the phpmyadmin database > privileges.

To maximize my ram I close all the applications and remove the Chrome running in background then restart again the installation process. I feel so frustrated and almost jump into WAMP but when I look on the phpmyadmin via browser it works perfectly fine like before on v5 - v7.

[phpMyAdmin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ZIKN.png)

Before it wasn't showing any pma there, but now it shows up. Hope this will helps future developers on their installation of XAMPP.