# #1030 - Got error 176 "Read page with wrong checksum" from storage engine Aria

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, mariadb

Created a new database but can't create new user account due to this error.
Does anyone know how to fix this? I can't find any solution to fix this.

> 1030 - Got error 176 "Read page with wrong checksum" from storage engine Aria

[image: error picture]

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58765779/mysql-issue-when-creating-a-new-user

Comment: You should tag this with the database server you're using, which I'm guessing could be MySQL or MariaDB from the error message. The tag you've used, phpmyadmin, is for an application that can help system administrators manage a MySQL or MariaDB instance, and isn't relevant here unless you're getting this error through phpMyAdmin itself (in which case you should indicate how exactly you're trying to create the user account).

Comment: Also read: [1030 – Got error 176 “Read the page with wrong checksum” from storage engine Aria](https://devnote.in/1030-got-error-176-read-the-page-with-wrong-checksum-from-storage-engine-aria/)

Comment: I got a similar error, I had entered into the particular database,- `use ecd`, then I had executed the same `mysql` query which I had tried,  but this time the error didn't occured.

Answer (score 308, accepted):

In my case above solution not worked. But the solution is similar to suggest by the [@user13439511](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13439511/user13439511)

Follow the below steps.

1. Select "**mysql**" database from the list of database.
   [image]
2. Select all tables inside "**mysql**" database.
   [image]
3. Scroll down and select "**Repair Table**" option in combobox.
4. Click on Go button.

Done.

Comment: Had this same error while editing privileges when my app crashed saying it had no permissions to the database. I ended up having to run "Repair Table" twice, then was able to edit the user and re-add the privileges (which were all gone). Thanks!

Comment: Wish I didn't drop and recreate the db before finding this, tnx!

Comment: Thanks! It works, but I'm also interested to know the cause of this problem

Comment: Using Xampp and from phpmyadmin trying to access useraccounts resulted in the error as titled. 
This solution worked to solve it.

Comment: **Not for InnoDB**: The solution mentioned above will not work on InnoDB. REPAIR TABLE works for MyISAM, ARCHIVE, and CSV tables. Here's the reference > https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/repair-table.html

Comment: it worked for me

Comment: @Dexter I have InnoDB, and it worked for me...

Comment: I got, "The storage engine for the table doesn't support repair"

Answer (score 21):

I was attempting to add a user to a new database with 'Privileges' and received this error:
"#1030 - Got error 176 "Read page with wrong checksum" from storage engine Aria"

Select mysql from the list of databases.  From the Table list, tick the box beside 'db'.  Scroll to the bottom of the page, in the selection box that says 'With selected' scroll down to and select 'Repair Table' then select 'Go'.  Worked for me
.:m

Answer (score 6):

Spent a long time trying to fix this, but the repair method wasn't working. MySQL repairs thinks it fixed all the tables, but it wasn't fixing the error (checking the tables showed they still had errors).

I did fix it by dropping and recreating the affected tables. Instructions as follows:

1. Select the 'mysql' database
2. Select all the tables as described in other fixes, but run a 'check tables' instead of a 'repair tables'.
3. For tables that are broken, (mine was the mysql.db table), you need to select the table and export it. In phpmyadmin, view the table and click export.
4. Select custom export, and check the 'Add DROP TABLE / TRIGGER statement' option, then export. Save the sql file.
5. In the import tab, import the sql file you just created.

This drops the table and recreates it, which fixed the issues I was having.

I'm not sure why this worked, where as repairing the table didn't.

Comment: Hi, I am not sure if anyone tries your solution before. But, I just tried and it solved my issue. Thanks for posting!!

Answer (score 1):

In the PHPMyAdmin panel go to the MySQL database, select the DB table and from the bottom dropdown menu select the repair table option.Your error will be resolved.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. While your contributions are welcome, please be sure to review the existing answers prior to adding a new one. In this case, there is already [an answer from last month](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61849288/3025856) with nine votes that provides the same guidance—along with more detailed explanation.

Answer (score 0):

In my phpMyAdmin version (5.0.4) the mysql db gets corrupted when stop and restart the MySQL server, I solved it by running the task as a service

Answer (score 0):

If you can't access to the structure of mysql database, just log out then try again to repaire tables of it.