# Phpmyadmin storage engine error 176 (and can´t repair table)

Tags: mysql, mariadb, innodb, wai-aria

Suddenly I have got a strange problem with phpmyadmin.
When trying to access privileges:
#1030 - Got error 176 "Read page with wrong checksum" from storage engine Aria

But I have not chosen to have Aria as Engine?  As default InnoDB
[screenshot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eLeYE.png)
More error message:
The phpMyAdmin configuration storage is not completely configured, some extended features have been deactivated. Find out why.
Or alternately go to 'Operations' tab of any database to set it up there.

configuration of pmadb not OK
General relation features Disabled
[screenshot pmadb, not ok](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nIRdZ.png)

But I have a database of PHPMyAdmin, and I have not changed anything in before
everything started to fail. Don't understand what to change?

### **OK so what have I tried:**

**Repair tables, as seen in this thread**  [#1030 - Got error 176 "Read page with wrong checksum" from storage engine Aria](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60864367/1030-got-error-176-read-page-with-wrong-checksum-from-storage-engine-aria)

Well did not work, mSg_text the storage engine for the table doesn´t support repair. As I understand it InnoDB cant repair tables. But then again why do I have this problem with Aria engine if I run InnoDB?
[repair table? screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ngn6e.png)
**Changed character set** for database PHPMyAdmin to utf8mb4_general_ci as I have on all other (no idea if this has any effect what so ever…)

**I have updated phpmyadmin to the latest version.**

**Then I tried to upgrade mariaDB** to the latest but run into problems when trying to run the mysql_upgrade.exe  file.  It does not create a data folder. I tried to copy the old, but these are the error messages I got.

2020-08-12 17:57:36 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Upgrade after a crash is not supported.

2020-08-12 17:57:36 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Plugin initialization aborted with error Generic error

2020-08-12 17:57:36 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
2020-08-12 17:57:36 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE

2020-08-12 17:57:36 0 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
2020-08-12 17:57:36 0 [ERROR] Aborting

So something strange is happing with the engine, but what, why and any ide on how to fix it?

Maybe it´s best just to destroy everything and start all over…

Comment: In the end I could not find a solution so I deleted the whole XAMMP and installed again.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, your system DOES use the Aria storage engine - look at the MySQL database itself and list the tables, you will see that several use ARIA and it is one or more of these that is broken. I have found it worthwhile to try and open each table, if it shows an error run `"repair table"` then `"flush table"` from phpMyAdmin. For me, it seems that the *_priv tables are the ones affected