# Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' when connecting to mysql

Tags: mysql, xampp

I have been researching this for close to 4 hours but still, I can't connect my Invision Community 4 forum to my mysql ran on localhost with xampp.

I can connect from the shell, but I can't connect to it from elsewhere.

`Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'`

Comment: maybe you need a password?

Comment: root has no password set, but even if I set one, it wont let me

Comment: you tagged it xampp so you must have installed it with a roorpassword, if you used the mysql installer you still was prompted to enter a password, the same goes safe installation script. 'Maybe start from the start and import the database after you can access , which begs te question how dod you import the database

Comment: I don't really know what you are referring to... I installed xampp and started an apache and mysql server. That's it.

Comment: the root password is empty see https://kinsta.com/knowledgebase/xampp-mysql-password/

Comment: Still, access denied.

Comment: run as then link shows the console from the xampp gui the re you should be logged in, from there you can follow the concepts that are presented in the link

Comment: But I still get access denied

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ERROR 1698 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39281594/error-1698-28000-access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost)

Answer (score 0):

I think that remote root access is disabled by default. Run this SQL command via the shell:

`GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password' WITH GRANT OPTION; FLUSH PRIVILEGES;`

Comment: Hey! Got an error when running FLUSH PRIVILEGES `ERROR 1030 (HY000): Got error 176 "Read page with wrong checksum" from storage engine Aria`

Comment: i don't know. a search yields this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61849288/3807365) so it might help

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you don't have the other "IPs" (like localhost) defined.
Follow these steps to fix it:

1. Execute this query: `` SELECT `Host`, `Password` FROM `mysql`.`user` WHERE USER = 'root'; ``
2. Check results, in this example the `pc` host has no password:

| Host | Password |
| --- | --- |
| localhost | *81F5E21E35407D000A6CD4A731AEBFB6AF209E1B |
| pc |  |
| 127.0.0.1 | *81F5E21E35407D000A6CD4A731AEBFB6AF209E1B |
| % | *81F5E21E35407D000A6CD4A731AEBFB6AF209E1B |

3. Check how are you connected: `SELECT CURRENT_USER();`:

| CURRENT_USER() |
| --- |
| root@localhost |

4. Now you know how you are connected and if all the user/host pairs share the
   same password or not, and maybe update the one that you want to change.

Comment: Please, if you like it, upvote my answer! to boost my profile :D

Comment: I don't have a password on localhost.

Answer (score 0):

you need to go to phpmyadmin - from there go to user accounts on the top menu : [phpmyadmin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TFnL3.png)
now click the root  account that has password set to yes next to it by clicking the usernameitself : [the root user with password](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9FGZ7.png)

[mysql - changing the root password - set it to no](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r4cwA.png)

after you enter the edit screen you will see an option "change password" on to
and now you can select "No password" :
[select change password from top](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lNEUT.png)

now select no password :
[set no password for the root](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mNxAv.png)

and save the query - you will no be able to login with only the host and username - hope it helps anyone :)